# How to create a sticky subtitle for each article?

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have the following html structure:

```html
<main class="previous-knowledge">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <section>
    <article>
      <h2>Subtitle 1</h2>
      <p>Very big paragraph 1</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>Subtitle 2</h2>
      <p>Very big paragraph 2</p>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

And the following css:

```css
main.previous-knowledge h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

I want to stick every subtitle while a user scrolls over every article, unfortunately, even when the subtitle stays stick on top, it does not "push" the `p` element. What I mean with push is that the `p` element stays below the `h2` while scrolling.

Comment: could you please explain about what you mean when you say "push the ```p``` element" ?

Comment: I will update my question.

Comment: *What I mean with push is that the p element stays below the h2 while scrolling.* --> this is contradictory with a sticky behavior

Comment: Maybe [this](https://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/AwBYPm) behavior can help to explain what I mean. Of course I want to achieve that without using JS.